# Where do you go to file a bug report for Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

does anyone know where to file a bug report for Jackson JSON?  thank you

I can't get Jackson to deserialize a JSON file. The inbound JSON has JSON null values, which I need to retain. ???

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized Type: [null]

Comment: Show what you tried, also, have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an issue on their Github Repository: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind